# Can we estimate the lower bound in this way?

Tags: sequences-and-series, integration, fourier-series

This post is aimed to find a lower bound of $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\cos(kx)}{k}$ for arbitrary $n \geq 1$

=================================

My approach:

Let $S_n(x)$ denote the partial sum of the below series:
$$\cos (x) + \frac{\cos( 2x)}{2} + \cdots + \frac{\cos( nx)}{n} + \cdots$$
becasue $\frac{\cos(kx)}{k}=\frac{1}{k}-\int_0^x\sin(kt)\mathrm{d}t$. $S_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}-\int_0^x\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin(kt)\mathrm{d}t$. Then I use Euler's Identity to facilitate the calculation of $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin (kt)=\frac{\sin(nt)}{2} +\frac{\sin(t)(1-\cos(nt))}{2(1-\cos(t))}$. but I have failed to integrate $$\int_0^x \frac{\sin(t)(1-\cos(nt))}{2(1-\cos(t))} \mathrm{d}t$$
Can we solve it by using the above idea or take some slightly modifying if necessary. Thanks very much

Comment: Is $n$ a fixed number or do you want the sum as $n\to\infty ?$

Comment: @Avatar, a fixed arbitrary number.

Answer (score 1):

By using the same idea, for $n\ne{0}$
$$\int\limits_{0}^{x}{e^{ikt}\ dt}=\dfrac{1}{ik}\left(e^{ikx}-1 \right),$$
therefore,
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{e^{ikx}}{k}-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k}=i\int\limits_{0}^{x}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{e^{ikt}\ dt}=i\int\limits_{0}^{x}{\dfrac{e^{it}\left(1-e^{int} \right)}{1-e^{it}}\ dt}=\\
=\int\limits_{0}^{x}{\dfrac{d(e^{it})}{1-e^{it}}}-\int\limits_{0}^{x}{\dfrac{e^{int}\ d(e^{it}) }{1-e^{it}}}.$$